# Javascript Calculate/Match Date and Datetime.now

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have date value from textbox below

```
01.01.2014
```

I want to match textbox date value to Datetime.now

```
Datetime.Now is 01.02.2014
```

I want to calculate datetime.now and textbox date value.

**Output must be below**

```
Datetime.now's days - DateTextbox value = 30 days

Datetime.now's month - DateTextbox value = 1 month

Datetime.now's year - DateTextbox value = 0 year
```

**So how can i do this by using only javascript ?**

**Html:**

```
<input type="text" id="DateTextBox"/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
    function GetDateButtonClick() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home/MyUrl",
            cache:false,
            data:
                {
                    MyDate: $("#DateTextBox").val(),
                },
            success: function (mydata) {

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Any help will be appreaciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to do it just in Javascript, why are you trying to post to something?

Comment: i need to post 3 results(year,month,days). I only did an example there.If there is code example , i will apply it totaly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get current date

```
var today = new Date();
```

Retrieve date from text box and convert to date object like this

```
var myDate = new Date("2014/1/1");
```

For comaparison

```
var timeDiff = Math.abs(myDate.getTime() - today.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); //this will give number of days
```

For the month of the year i will leave that to you...Hope this helps

**UPDATE**

```
var diffMonths = Math.round(((diffDays / 30); // for months
var diffYrs = Math.round(diffMonths / 12); // for years
```

Comment: Don't leave it to me please , may you share for month too ? I need to see another writing example for code

Answer (score 0):

This will find you the number of years, months, days, hours, minutes between the two dates.

```
var today = new Date();
var inputDate = new Date($("#DateTextBox").val());// from your input

var diffSecs = (inputDate - today)/1000; // seconds between today & inputDate

var diffMins = Math.round(diffSecs / 60); // minutes
var diffHrs = Math.round(diffMins / 60); // hours
var diffDays = Math.round(diffDays / 24); // days
var diffMonths = Math.round(((diffDays / 30); // months
var diffYrs = Math.round(diffMonths / 12); // years

alert(diffYrs + " years, " + diffMonths + " months, " + diffDays + " days, " + diffHrs + " hours, " + diffMins + " minutes.");
```